# VSTS is not allowing me to commit my code in GIT. I'm getting error "git-commit contains sensitive data". I want to commit code ignoring this error,

Tags: visual-studio, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, github-actions

[image]

VSTS is not allowing me to commit my code in GIT. I'm getting error "git-commit contains sensitive data". I want to commit code ignoring this error,

I want to commit and ignore these error messages and why this messages are occuring

Comment: _"I want to commit code ignoring this error,"_ - yes, well, **your boss disagrees** - take it up with them, not us. You can't fight a remote computer system, so all you can do is plead to your devops admins to give you an exception from the policy, and if they won't give you one then maybe you shouldn't put passwords in source-code...

Comment: What software is causing this message?  Is this a message you're seeing from a hook on your system or a message you're seeing on a website related to your push?  If so, what website?

Answer (score 0):

Committing passwords as plain text in source code is a security vulnerability, especially if this code will be published to a public repository like GitHub. There is no single solution to resolve this, but generally you need to:

1. Not commit passwords to source code.
2. Any application that requires a password or authentication token (more generally called a "secret") should retrieve this from a secure location. This is dependent on technology stack, but many DevOps-style systems have a password vault or secrets vault that provides this functionality.
3. Passwords or auth tokens become data/configuration specified at deployment time, rather than hard coded in a config file.

As others have suggested in comments, you need to consult with your team. Clearly you have a need for a password. Your team lead or software architect will probably have a solution for this. Unless you *are* the team lead or architect, in which case you get to decide the solution given the guidelines above.